# Replace angle brackets with XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to print the code of my XML on an html page. The XML-file is processed by an XSLT Stylesheet.

At the moment I am trying to do the following:

```
<xsl:template name="XML">
        <pre>
          <code>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"></xsl:copy-of>
          </code>
        </pre>
 </xsl:template>
```

And this works pretty fine, but the XML-Code isn't displayed, because the browser interprets the actual markup of the XML-Code. So is there a solution to replace the angle brackets with `&lt;` and `&gt;` ?

Comment: If you use an XSLT 3 processor you can use the `serialize` function on any node. There are also processor specific extension functions for non-XSLT 3 processors and there are complex but tested pure XSLT 1 solutions like https://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/.

Comment: The `<xmp>` tag can be handy here as an alternative to `<pre>`. All the documentation claims that it's obsolete and deprecated, but it works for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 3 you can simply use `<xsl:value-of select="serialize(node())"/>` instead of the `<xsl:copy-of select="node()"></xsl:copy-of>` you have tried.

For older XSLT processors not supporting XSLT 3 there might be a processor specific extension function to serialize nodes or you can use existing, worked out, pure XSLT approaches to serialization like https://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/.